# Problema con Modulo mpi4py

Tags: python

Encontré un modulo interesante para hacer cálculos paralelos con `python` pero al usar la documentación me dice que el código para empezar a usar el modulo es este pero cuando trato de ejecutar el código me sale un error:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = mpi4py.MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
print "HOla", rank
```

pero obtengo este error en la consola

> C:\Users\LUIGGI-S>C:\Users\LUIGGI-S\Desktop\cluster.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\LUIGGI-S\Desktop\cluster.py", line 3, in 
>       comm = mpi4py.MPI.COMM_WORLD
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MPI'

¿Cuál podría ser la solución?

Comment: ¿Tienes MPI instalado? Como estás en Windows quizá lo más fácil sea usando https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524831(v=vs.85).aspx. Si instalando lo detallado en el anterior enlace no te resuelve el problema échale un ojo a https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/appendix.html#building-mpi. De todas formas, hay otras opciones para correr código paralelizado en Python.

Comment: Gracias @kikocorreoso instale ese modulo de python con pip asi poniendo en consola  :  pip install mpi4py ,deberia instalar algo mas? quisiera hacerlo con "mpi4py porque me gusta python tengo algo de experiencia y porque  veo que hay mucha ayuda en internet sobre ese modulo

Comment: Relee el comentario anterior y sigue las instrucciones. Además de instalar mpi4py necesitas instalar una implementación de MPI para windows.

Comment: @kikocorreoso Funciono !!!! gracias por la ayuda , instale el MPI que me dejaste en el link y ejecute el archivo python de arriba y funciono

Comment: Perfecto, pues convierto el primer comentario en respuesta y le das a aprobar para que otros puedan encontrar una solución satisfactoria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Tienes MPI instalado? Como estás en Windows quizá lo más fácil sea usando

- Lo disponible en este [enlace de Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524831(v=vs.85).aspx).

Si instalando lo detallado en el anterior enlace no te resuelve el problema échale un ojo a:

- La documentación oficial de [*mpi4py*](http://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/appendix.html#building-mpi).

Por completar la respuesta, hay otras opciones para correr código [paralelizado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing) en Python. Dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer unas soluciones se ajustarán mejor o peor:

- En la librería estándar tienes [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html),...
- [ipyparallel](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [joblib](http://pythonhosted.org/joblib)
- [deco](https://github.com/alex-sherman/deco)
- [cython](http://cython.org/)
- [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)
- ...

Answer (score 1):

Creo que es un error en tu código. En el tutorial oficial http://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#point-to-point-communication tienes:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
```

Mientras que tú has escrito

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = mpi4py.MPI.COMM_WORLD  # <--- ¡Aquí!
rank = comm.Get_rank()
```

Prueba exactamente el código del tutorial no vaya a ser que tengas MPI instalado y no estés accediendo bien.

Comment: gracias tienes razon tenia ese error en el codigo ,que bueno que queda expuesto aqui para que alguien mas le pueda servir

Comment: Sin ánimo de quitar mérito a mi compañero @kikocorreoso, propongo que marques esta respuesta como buena entonces :)

Comment: jajajaja listo compañero :D